# Populating values in the continuous Form after pressing a command button in Ms Access 2016

Tags: vba, forms, events, ms-access-2016, continuous

I have continuous Form (part of the Main Form)
I need to create a button after pressing on which - only specific values should populate across the entire Form.

The Form tied to Category-Objective table with the following values -

[image]

My **YesNoFK** field has values  Yes = 1, No=2

In my Form, when user will click "Comma" button I want him to see all "Yes" values auto-populated into
Complaint (it is the caption of YesNoFk field):

[image]

Please, HELP!

Comment: questions: 

1. Is the complaint field bound to a database field?  
2. Is this a sub-form to a main form?   
3. Is the form filtered to only show the records for one "main" record?   

If they are, you can use that info to create an update query to set them in a couple of lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

If everyone wants this set, have you considered setting the default value for the compliant combo box in the table design?